# Best way to display a coming soon link

Tags: navigation, hyperlinks, simplicity, minimalist

I have a link in my navigation and I want users to know that that link is soon to be uploaded. I displayed a badge next to it saying the message but it brings too much attention. What's the most unobtrusive and minimal way to send the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could have a washed out version of a highlighted color and have a coming soon message as a tooltip on hover.

the highlighted color will give attention that this is something new (you could standardise this across your ui and assign a certain color for new features or links) at the same time have this link disabled with a faded version (e.g. disabled link that was black or white would be grey). This gives the user the indication that the link isn't clickable.